# What is the position-space form of the photon propagator in axial gauge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, greens-functions, propagator, analyticity

I'm interested in the form of the photon propagator in position space, when expressed in an axial gauge $ n \cdot A  =0$, where in the case I am interested in, $n^\mu = \{1,0,0 \dots, 0\}$ (for a $D$-dimensional flat spacetime).

The Fourier space propagator has the form
$$
G_{\mu \nu}(p) = -i \left(g_{\mu \nu}-\frac{\left(n_\mu p_\nu+n_\nu p_\mu\right)}{n \cdot p}+n \cdot n \frac{p_\mu p_\nu}{(n \cdot p)^2}\right) \frac{1}{p^2}
$$

where here in particular $n \cdot p = -p^0$.

My question is what is the expression of the position space propagator ? I know I must compute the inverse Fourier transform, where terms like $p_\mu$ would be replaced by a $i \partial_\mu$, but what about the $ 1/(n \cdot p)$ terms?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the equation of motion of the free photon in axial gauge and compute the Green function in position-space directly?

Comment: No I haven't tried, I thought it would be faster to start directly from the already known Fourier space expression but indeed I should try and do that.